# QMenu action creation in a range

Tags: pyside

I would create a qMenu which lines contain a list af file name. It's a variable length list. I would like to do a simple script where I would choose a
simple line (file) from it.

```
from PySide import QtGui

def a():
    print "Here i should know which menu is called."


mpos = QtGui.QCursor
x = mpos.pos().x()
y = mpos.pos().y()
# print x,y


app = QtGui.QApplication(())
m = QtGui.QMenu()

for i in range(22):
    m.addAction('Menu '+str(i), a)

m.setGeometry( x-20, y-20, 0, 0)
# m.hideTearOffMenu()
# m.setTitle("hh")

# action1.triggered.connect( a)
m.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the signal from *each* action to its *own* behaviour.  This could be done quite pythonically something like this:

```
def create_callable_for(i):
    def f():
        print("hello",i)
    return f

for i in range(22):
   m.addAction('Menu '+str(i), create_callable_for(i))
```

However personally I prefer to use `functools.partial` like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    fileMenu.addAction(a,functools.partial(print,"Hello",i))
```

For each menu item you create a callable that contains (in a closure) the value that distinguishes that action from the rest in the menu.  Here it is the int `i` but it could just as well be a file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a slot to the menu's [triggered](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#triggered) signal, which sends the action that was selected:

```
def a(action):
    print "Here i should know which menu is called."
    print unicode(action.text())

...

m.triggered.connect(a)
```

Alternatively, the [exec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#exec) function directly returns the action that was selected (or `None` if nothing was selected). So you could also do:

```
action = m.exec_()
if action is not None:
    print unicode(action.text())
else:
    print 'nothing selected'
```